# How do I send push notifications to Android devices?

Tags: android

How do I send push notifications to Android devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a service called **Android C2DM** (*Cloud-to-Device-Messaging*). It will allow you to send messages/alerts to your device when requested. For more info, read [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter) and for registeration, click [this](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/).

Answer (score 0):

http://souravtechdiary.blogspot.in/2012/03/implementing-push-notifications-for.html

Hope it helps as the working is

Comment: Thank you Mainank Brahmbhatt............